# Code doesn't read the last character of string of Characters (C language)

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {
  char input[10];
  char standart;
  int i;
  int b = 0;

  scanf("%c", &standart);

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    scanf("%c ", &input[i]);
    if(input[i] == standart){
      b++;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", b);
  return 0;
}

// ( 2 % a b ( r ) ? ( (
```

The code is suppost to read the first character in the list, then see how many of said characters there are (not including itself).  But the code doesn't read the last character, in short when I input the sample input the code only sees 2 '(' while it should see 3.

Comment: Is it not reading i == 0, i == 1 ... i == 9?
Unless my math is wrong that makes 10.
Plus even if I make the array size 11 it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Change the `for` loop `scanf` statement to -> `scanf(" %c", &input[i]);`. Removed the space after `%c` and added a space before `%c`.

Comment: First ( goes into standart not the array

Comment: Thank you H.S that's fixed it, hadn't noticed that space there!  Is it because it was looking for a space after the last character but couldn't find one so it couldn't save it into the array?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this `scanf(" %c",&c);`
Because it reads '\n' from previous input, so the space will skip the '\n'

Answer (score 0):

For the given input `( 2 % a b ( r ) ? ( (`, the program takes the first character `(` as input to variable `standart` -

```
scanf("%c", &standart);
```

The problem is occurring because in the first iteration of `for` loop the `scanf` was reading the first whitespace character (a blank space) from given input that exists after `(` and storing it into `input[0]`.
The `for` loop runs for 10 iterations and the last character `(` is not inserted in the `input` array because of which the `standart` character count in `input` array is coming one less than expected i.e. 2.

Change the `for` loop `scanf` statement to -

```
scanf(" %c", &input[i]); //Removed the space after %c and added a space before %c.
```

With this, the for loop `scanf` will eat whitespaces characters. 
So, the next character from input - `2` will be stored to `input[0]` and `%` will be stored to `input[1]` and so on and the last character '(' will be stored to `input[9]`.
And the `b` will have the correct `standart` character count in `input` array i.e. 3.